# How do I view flash cookies using Chrome in Selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, flash, cookies

I am trying to use selenium with .NET (C#) to pull Flash cookies from a particular URL (in this case, a game on kongregate). I know where the flash cookies are stored physically for the browser I use personally. I attempted to access the flash cookies using the physical location in google Chrome's directory (Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot#SharedObjects), however this has no effect on the flash cookies a gather using selenium. How can I get access to the Shared Object files that are stored through my selenium instance?

Comment: Please post the code you tried. Have you tried loading a profile and then accessing it?

Comment: @JeffC I haven't tried loading a profile. I didn't realize that data was stored in a profile, but I looked into it and that solved my problem. Thanks! What's the protocol for a question answered in the comments? Should I close the question, edit the question, or answer it in an answer?

Comment: I posted an answer. Feel free to edit it if there's something crucial that is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading a custom Chrome profile and see if that helps. Here's a quick example.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) for more details.